# Android Many Nested Activities Problem

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an android application in which I have a **ParentActivity** class as follows.

```
public class ParentActivity extends Activity {
   protected void navigateForResult(Context c, Class<?> destination, int requestCode) {
    Intent i = new Intent(c, destination);
    startActivityForResult(i, requestCode);
   }
}
```

My all other activities are inherited from this activity. Now I have an activity called **CategoryListActivity** which is inherited from **ParentActivity**. The **CategoryListActivity** invokes another activity named **SubCategoryListActivity** using the function from **ParentActivity** named **navigateForResult**.

In **SubCategoryListActivity** I have following code in some event which is definitely fired.

```
...
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
finishActivity(5);
```

I also have **onActivityResult** function in **CategoryListActivity** but this is not fired. Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the bug. The **finishActivity(with response code)** doesn't really work. I have to use **finish()** instead